# Android app's Bluetooth BLE scan stop when advertising stops. Why?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, scanning

I have an Android 6 -  level 23 application running on mobile devices that both concurrently advertises and scans BLE connectionless packets.

ISSUE:

I find that when I call stopAdvertising(), the continuous running BLE scan operation is halted or stops working for 1-4 seconds, before resuming again.  I know this because I can readily see the continually received ad packets every 0.10 second are not received for 1-4 seconds.  This implies the scan operation is halted or stopped when the advertise operation is programmatically stopped.

How can I periodically start and stop BLE advertising **without adversely messing up** the BLE scanning operation?

I tried developing my application using different Android version APIs with the same annoying scan halt problem:
Android 6 - level 23
Android 8 level 26

Just for reference, here's some snippets of Android 6 code:

```
       // create advertiser and save in list, so advertising instance can be stopped in future.           
       mBluetoothAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

       // start advertising!
       mBluetoothAdvertiser.startAdvertising( settings, data, mBluetoothAdvertiseCallback );

       // do some work...

      // TESTED BAD - the call below causes the BLE scan operation to halt for 1-4 seconds.
       mBluetoothAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mBluetoothAdvertiseCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android's Bluetooth stack, scanning and advertising are completely independent. All operations are simply sent to the Bluetooth chip and it's up to its firmware to scan and advertise.

The Bluetooth chip, that usually only has one radio, needs to schedule scanning and advertising since only one operation can be performed at the same time.

Apparently you see an effect of this. The scheduling algorithms used by different Bluetooth chip manufacturers are proprietary and usually not public. You have to ask the manufacturer of the specific device you are using why they behave in a particular way.

Android however sends a hint of the scan interval. In Android the interval is 5 seconds, so that probably influences your results.

Comment: Thank you kindly Emil for your answer!   -Ken